# Swift 3, Xcode 8.0 Playground выдаёт ошибку: «The LLDB RPC server has crashed»

Tags: массивы, xcode, swift, структуры-данных, динамические-массивы

Задание следующее:

> Написать функцию, принимающую натуральное число N.
>   Одномерный массив размером N заполнить случайными числами.   Вывести на экран количество простых чисел в массиве (Для удобства проверки дополнительно вывести сгенерированный массив). 
>   Для генерации простого числа можно использовать глобальную функцию arc4random(). Следует обратить внимание, что функция возвращает значение типа UInt32 (потребуется преобразование), а также работает на всем диапазоне (можно применить arc4random() % 100 для получения чисел в промежутке [0, 100) )

Моя реализация ниже на **Swift 3** в Playground:

```
import Foundation

func createRandomArray(withLength n: Int) -> Any {
    if n == 0 || n < 0 {
        return 0
    }

    var generatedArray: [Int?] = []
    var primeNumbers:   [Int?] = []

    for _ in 1...n {
        generatedArray.append(Int(arc4random() % 100))
    }

    thisWay: for number in generatedArray {
        // Избегаю деления элемента массива на самого себя, 
        // так как понятно, что при делении числа на самого себя
        // остаток будет 0.
        let preNumber = generatedArray[number!]! - 1
        for divider in preNumber..<1 {
            if generatedArray[number!]! % divider == 0 {
                continue thisWay
            } else {
                primeNumbers.append(generatedArray[number!]!)
            }
        }
    }
    // Выводим тапл.
    return (generatedArray, primeNumbers)
}

createRandomArray(withNumberOfElements: 13)
```

Выводит непредвиденную ошибку:
[image]

Синтаксические ошибки отсутствуют, если верить IDE. С дебаггером пока работать не умею – только начал осваивать Swift разработку в Xcode.

**Вопрос**: что неправильно в моём коде? Или хотя бы подсказке буду признателен.

Comment: валится оно потому, что вы пытаетесь вернуть два значения. Еще уберите '?' в объявлении массивов. они там лишние и помогут избавиться от всех '!'. через часик придут неленивые, перепишут вам поиск простых чисел.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, в проверке

```
if n == 0 || n < 0 {
    return 0
}
```

2 условия можно заменить на одно:

```
if n < 1 {
```

Далее,

```
var generatedArray: [Int?] = []
var primeNumbers:   [Int?] = []
```

заменяем на

```
var generatedArray = [Int]()
var primeNumbers = [Int]()
```

Возвращать функция, как я понял, должна у Вас 2 массива, пусть будет так:

```
func createRandomArrays(withLength n: Int) -> (generatedArray: [Int], primesArray: [Int])?
```

Так как Вы в цикле проходитесь по элементам, а не по индексам, то не

```
generatedArray[number!]!
```

а просто `number`.

Ну и насколько помню поиск простых чисел, то в конечном итоге будет такой результат:

```
func createRandomArrays(withLength n: Int) -> (generatedArray: [Int], primesArray: [Int])? {
    if n < 1 {
        return nil
    }
    var generatedArray = [Int]()
    var primesArray = [Int]()
    for _ in 1...n {
        generatedArray.append(Int(arc4random() % 100))
    }
    thisWay: for number in generatedArray {
        if number < 4 {
            primesArray.append(number)
            continue
        }
        let maxCondition = Int(sqrt(Double(number)))
        for divider in 2...maxCondition {
            if number % divider == 0 {
                continue thisWay
            }
        }
        primesArray.append(number)
    }
    return (generatedArray, primesArray)
}

var generateLength = 13

if let generatedArrays = createRandomArrays(withLength: generateLength) {
    print("Generated array: \(generatedArrays.generatedArray)")
    print("Primes array: \(generatedArrays.primesArray)")
    print("Primes count: \(generatedArrays.primesArray.count)")
} else {
    print("generateLength < 1")
}
```